# Переменная из фукции в глобальную

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь написать для упрощения жизни бота телеграм на питоне.
Есть код. в котором при использовании /add вылазят кнопки и нажимая на которые поочередно формируется ответ. Мне требуется что бы этот ответ (call_backdata) записывался в Глобальную переменную (как вариант в виде списка).

```
import telebot
from keyboa import keyboa_maker
from telnet import sn
import os
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')


vlans = ['2' , '4', '5' , '7', '213']


def sn_list():
    kb_sn = keyboa_maker(items=sn, copy_text_to_callback=True)
    return kb_sn

def vlan_list():
    kb_vlan = keyboa_maker(items=vlans, copy_text_to_callback=True)
    return kb_vlan


@bot.message_handler(commands=['add'])
def command_add(m):
    if m.from_user.id == [id]:
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=m.from_user.id, reply_markup=sn_list(),
            text="Список неавторизованых:")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.from_user.id == [id]: #отвечать только мне
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'hi')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
def query_handler(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='')
    if call.data in sn:
        parametrs.append(call.data)
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=call.from_user.id, reply_markup=vlan_list(),
            text="Список vlan:")

    elif call.data in vlans :
        parametrs.append(call.data)
        answer = ''
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, answer)





bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема в сохранении данных в глобальную переменную?

Comment: не сохраняет. Пытался вести глобальную переменную (к примеру x = [] ) и в теле функции делал x.append = call.data  . в итоге список x остается пустым

Comment: добавил ответ про работу с глобальной переменной

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример работы с глобальной переменной:

```py
g = "Hello"

def fun():
    global g # Указываем что g является глобальной а не локальной
    g = "world"

fun()
print(g) # world
```

Если не указать global

```py
g = "Hello"

def fun():
    g = "world" # g Локальная существует только в пределах fun()

fun()
print(g) # Hello
```

Comment: переменная срабатывает. Но получился казус... Если боту одновременно пишут 2+ человека. Переменные перепутываются. Получается примерно так:
пользователь 1 ответил на 2 вопроса (10 и 20) и оба его ответа перешли в переменную (к примеру х и у)
Пользователь 2 ответил на 1 вопрос и его ответ записался в переменную Х  - 5
В итоге пользователь 1 получает ответ x+y = 25 а не 30(согласно его ответам)

Comment: Это собственно к вопросу почему использование глобальных переменных не есть хорошо. По большому счету можно обернуть код в класс и хранить данные в полях класса. тогда каждый экземпляр класса будет иметь свои данные. Можно использовать @dataclass  для хранения данных, или через глобальные переменные хранить в словаре типа {id сессии: значение}.

Comment: С классами разобрался. но видать не полностью. получается всеровно класс хранит последнюю переменную. Наверно мой выход использовать словарь.

Comment: Со словарем главное определите логику его очистки, а то хранить вечно данные как то не очень нужно.